# Write ML function

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm new to ML so I'm doing my best to understand.

Write an ML function called `alternate : 'a list -> 'a list`, that takes two lists, having the same length, as input and produces an output list whose elements are alternately taken from the first and second input list respectively.

**Example**

```
alternate ([1,3,5],[2,4,6]) = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

This is my work : `fun alternate ( x::xs,y::ys) = x::alternate(x,y);`

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and __a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.__*

Comment: The type signature that you give ( `alternate : 'a list -> 'a list` ) doesn't match the rest of the question (which seems to be about (`alternate : 'a list * 'a list -> 'a list`). In any event, here is a hint: the recursive case can involve the swapping of the order of the two arguments so what plays the role of `x` in one call will play the role of `y` in the next, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You split the problem in two: A recursive case and a base case. *(1)* In the recursive case you solve some unit of the problem, in this case placing a single element from each list in front of the result, and recursively try to solve the rest of the problem in the same fashion. *(2)* In the base case, the lists are empty and the result is the empty list.

```
fun alternate (x::xs, y::ys) = x::y::alternate(xs, ys)
  | alternate ([], []) = []
  | alternate _ = raise Fail "xs and ys don't have the same length"
```

*(3)* Because the function is only well-defined for input of even length, the catch-all pattern `_` matches the two-tuple containing lists where one is empty and the other isn't and raises an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation